# Catch call to new AbortController()

Tags: javascript, jestjs

I have this piece of code:

```js
if (this.isRequestPending) {
  this.conversationsAbortController.abort()
  this.conversationsAbortController = new AbortController()
}
```

I'm already able to catch the call to `.abort()` using `jest.spyOn(AbortController.prototype, 'abort')` but I'd like to also catch the `new AbortController()`.

I've tried:

- `jest.spyOn(AbortController.prototype, 'new')`
- `jest.spyOn(AbortController.prototype, 'constructor')`
- `jest.spyOn(AbortController.prototype, 'AbortController')`

But it doesn't seem to work.

I did look at the `global.d.ts` file for this:

```js
interface AbortController {
  /**
   * Returns the AbortSignal object associated with this object.
   */

  readonly signal: AbortSignal;
  /**
   * Invoking this method will set this object's AbortSignal's aborted flag and signal to any observers that the associated activity is to be aborted.
   */
  abort(): void;
}

/** A signal object that allows you to communicate with a DOM request (such as a Fetch) and abort it if required via an AbortController object. */
interface AbortSignal {
  /**
   * Returns true if this AbortSignal's AbortController has signaled to abort, and false otherwise.
   */
  readonly aborted: boolean;
}

declare var AbortController: {
  prototype: AbortController;
  new(): AbortController;
};

declare var AbortSignal: {
  prototype: AbortSignal;
  new(): AbortSignal;
  // TODO: Add abort() static
};
```

But I'm not sure what to make of it.